# Viewpager - how to update args of the next page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I've got a ViewPager with 3 pages or tabs.

In the first tab it has a fragment with a listview.
That listview contains books of the Bible.

In the second tab it has a fragment with a TableLayout with a number of chapters of the previously selected book.

The same with the Last tab obtaining verses of the selected chapter.

My problem is:

FragmentPagerAdapter loads the tab 1 and tab 2 at the beginning so the list of chapters to show doesn't correspond to the book when I select it.

So how I do to the fragment Chapter update when I select the book?

Thanks and sorry about my english

Comment: Sounds like you need a Master/Detail view instead of a ViewPager

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is this example with one additional Fragment.  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overide a **setUserVisibleHint** method in your Chapter Fragment.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
    //do your task here  
   }
}
```

This method will invoke only when fragment is visible to you.

Comment: Then in that method I update the selected book and how I update the view of fragment? Because in onCreateView and onViewCreated I set the view :S

Comment: Once you set the view it doesn't mean you can't update that. As you are going to dynamically set the view in second fragment according to the first fragment, so you can define the view in onCreateView() method and update it in setUserVisibleHint().

Comment: I remove from onCreateView my TableLayout and I put it in the setUserVisibleHint, so when that tab is visible I building the content, else the content set double. Thanks for the hint!